# Normalization of Bounding Box for visualizing some LIDAR data

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, python-imaging-library, lidar

I am trying to convert these annotations to a pixel form and plot them on their image. This is what the annotations look like:

> - `px`: x-axis center of bounding box in meters within the range of [-20m, 20m]
> - `py`: y-axis center of bounding box in meters within the range of [1m, 24m]
> - `wid`: width of bounding box in meters (corresponding to x-axis)
> - `len`: lengt of bounding box in meters (corresponding to y-axis)

I am trying to convert px,py to [0,1]. This is the code I have come up with so far, the bounding boxes are not coinciding with the image at all:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
from IPython.display import display

for idx, row in df.sample(10).iterrows():
    image_path = f"../input/lidar-detection/Automotive/Automotive/{row['Folder Name']}/images_0/{row['CSV File Name']}"
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    
    # Normalize the coordinates and dimensions
    px = (row['PX'] + 20) / 40  # Adjusted the divisor to 40
    py = (row['PY'] - 1) / 23   # Adjusted the divisor to 22 + 1 = 23
    wid = row['WID'] / 40
    length = row['LEN'] / 22
    
    x_size, y_size = image.size
    px *= x_size
    py *= y_size
    w = wid * x_size
    h = length * y_size
    
    draw.rectangle(((px - w / 2, py - h / 2), (px + w / 2, py + h / 2)), outline="blue", width=3)
    
    display(image)
```

I tried to normalize the co-ordinates to [0,1], and the values I get do seem to belong to that range, but when plotting the bounding box on top of the images, the boxes are all random

Comment: since that is lidar data, you might wanna use a plotting library instead of PIL